# .NET MAUI Cancel disappearing event when changes are detected to View

Tags: c#, android, maui

Im trying to cancel the disappearing event if user made a change to any textbox , i want to bring up a modal to ask "Exit without saving"?

I tried overriding the Page class event, but did not succeed.

```
//override base class Page
 protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        // find if textbox value has changed
        bool hasChanges = FindChanges();

        if (hasChanges)
        {
            //show dialog here , cancel page exit
            //.PushAsync(YesNoModal)
            return;
        }
        //continue normally
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
```

it just exits the page on return;

Im not sure is there a command to stop page closing

Comment: I tested it and as you said that "it just exits the page on return;". You want to make a "Exit without saving" when you tap `Back` to return to the previous page?

Comment: yes i dialog but i cannot cancel the disappearing event/override like on winforms , i also cannot hide the return arrow. I have content page when user press back button must check for changes in textboxes if any cancel the event. Its not possible?

Comment: I try to achieve it in ·OnBackButtonPressed· method but failed. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GphDE.png). For MAUI, when execute disappearing event, it has returned to the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `OnBackButtonPressed` doesn't support async method(`DisplayAlert`), you can use the following code to achieve it:

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    int i = 0;
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("Page3", typeof(NewPage3));
    }
    protected override async void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Current != null && args.Current.Location.OriginalString.Contains("Page3"))
        {
            var currentpage = (App.Current.MainPage as AppShell).CurrentPage as NewPage3;
            if (currentpage is NewPage3)
            {
                bool value = false;
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    args.Cancel();
                    value = await DisplayAlert("Note:", "Exit without saving?", "Yes", "NO");
                    if (value == true)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                if (value == true)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(args.Target.Location.OriginalString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Previous != null)
        {
            if (args.Previous.Location.OriginalString.Contains("Page3"))
                i = 0;
        }
        base.OnNavigated(args);
    }
}
```

The above overrides Shell's `OnNavigating` and `OnNavigated` methods. `NewPage3` represents a page with textbox. You can create several pages to test it. When leaving the `NewPage3` and returning to the previous page, it will bring up a popup to ask "Exit without saving".

This is the only way I can think of to achieve it at the moment. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for taking time , i will see if i can implement

Comment: It works , for now this is a good workaround thank you